# unit test if publish was executed inside another publish

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

is it possible to test if eventAggregator.publish was executed during another publish?

```js
this.eventAggregator.with(this).subscribe(Xevent, (event: Xevent) => {
    this.eventAggregator.publish(new anotherEvent());
});
```

If I test it like this:

```js
describe('when X event is published', () => {
            it('then Y event should be published', () => {
                //arrange
                let event = new Xevent();
                spyOn(evtAggregator, 'publish');
                //act
                evtAggregator.publish(event);
                //assert
                expect(evtAggregator.publish).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new anotherEvent());
            });
        });
```

jasmine gives me an error that event Aggregator was called with "Xevent":

> Expected spy publish to have been called with [ anotherEvent ... ]
> but actual calls were [ Xevent ...]

Can I assert it a different way or am I something missing in arrange section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add "[.and.callThrough()](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callThrough%3C/code%3E)" for spy:

```js
describe('when X event is published', () => {
            it('then Y event should be published', () => {
                //arrange
                let event = new Xevent();
                spyOn(evtAggregator, 'publish').and.callThrough(); //here is the change
                //act
                evtAggregator.publish(event);
                //assert
                expect(evtAggregator.publish).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new anotherEvent());
            });
        });
```

Simpler than I thought.